# Possible to see tracing when using cat or vi opening a text file

Tags: bpf, ebpf, bcc-bpf

Is it possible to trace through what is being read through a text file using eBPF? There are ways to see the amount of memory being used and count reads and writes but I would like to even output the user data using bpf_trace_print if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would require tracing `open()` (or `openat()`) system call and correlate it (fd in particular) with traced `read` calls.

`/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/syscalls/sys_enter_read/format` defines what syscall arguments can be accessed. What may interest you is `char *buf` buffer pointer, where `read()` places bytes it has read.

However, it is possible that the trace call occurs *before* any bytes have been read (need to check the kernel source). So, may be more reliable way is to use raw tracepoint (`BPF_PROG_TYPE_RAW_TRACEPOINT`) hooked at read() return.

Comment: It might be going over my head a little bit but is this just a matter of doing b.attach_raw_tracepoint(,.. ,...) or doing b.attach_kprobe(.. ,sym="read", ..)? I'm not sure on how I can see the values inside char *buf